# glassfish nested connection pool error

Tags: mysql, glassfish, connection-pooling

I have made a mysql connection pool in glassfish.

After every 5 mins its giving this error **although i can use the connection pool.**

```
 SEVERE: Sat Jul 09 13:57:05 IST 2011 WARN: Caught while disconnecting...
 EXCEPTION STACK TRACE:
 ** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 
 java.net.SocketException   
MESSAGE: Socket is not connected
STACKTRACE:
java.net.SocketException: Socket is not connected
at java.net.Socket.shutdownInput(Socket.java:1379)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.quit(MysqlIO.java:1686)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.realClose(ConnectionImpl.java:4388)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.close(ConnectionImpl.java:1564)
at com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlPooledConnection.close(MysqlPooledConnection.java:205)
at com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.JDBC4MysqlXAConnection.close(JDBC4MysqlXAConnection.java:49)
at com.sun.gjc.spi.ManagedConnection.destroy(ManagedConnection.java:399)
at com.sun.enterprise.resource.allocator.ConnectorAllocator.destroyResource(ConnectorAllocator.java:196)
at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.deleteResource(ConnectionPool.java:955)
at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.datastructure.RWLockDataStructure.removeResource(RWLockDataStructure.java:153)
at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.resizer.Resizer.removeIdleAndInvalidResources(Resizer.java:207)
at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.resizer.Resizer.resizePool(Resizer.java:113)
at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.resizer.Resizer.run(Resizer.java:93)
at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:512)
at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:462)
** END NESTED EXCEPTION **
```

The mysql config file(my.ini) is

```
[client]



port=3306



[mysql]



default-character-set=utf8





[mysqld]


port=3306






basedir="P:/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.5/"



datadir="P:/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.5/Data/"


character-set-server=utf8


default-storage-engine=INNODB


sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"


max_connections = 200



query_cache_size=32M




table_cache=256


tmp_table_size=35M


thread_cache_size=8



myisam_max_sort_file_size=100G


myisam_sort_buffer_size=69M


key_buffer_size=49M


read_buffer_size=64K

read_rnd_buffer_size=256K


sort_buffer_size=256K

innodb_data_home_dir="P:/MySQL Datafiles/"






innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=2M


innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1



innodb_log_buffer_size=1M


innodb_buffer_pool_size=94M




innodb_log_file_size=19M


innodb_thread_concurrency=8



enable-named-pipe

max_allowed_packet = 200M
```

btw where can i find the glassfish bugzilla

thanks

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be similar to the issue I am having: [Named Pipe connection throws warning on close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7509739/java-mysql-named-pipe-connection-throws-warning-on-close). Whenever a named pipe connection is "closed", this warning is thrown. Furthermore, it is evident after monitoring the database that the connection isn't actually closed on the mysql end.